# Panel and ScrollBar in Windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, panel

I am using a panel to display a image in windows forms
I am drawing image in the panel in Panel_Paint event as follows:

```
Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
Image im = new Bitmap(@"../../Data/#3_Page2.PNG");
g.DrawImage(im,new Point(10,10));
```

Now, the image is drawn as i expected, with some part of the bottom of the image not displaying as its height is greater than forms height.
I have added the VScrollBar now. How do i make that panel to view the rest of the image with the help of VScrollBar.

Comment: The Panel.VerticalScroll property provides the required behaviour

Comment: @ViacheslavSmityukh however I think it's not useful with custom paint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution works, however if your image is large enough, there is a little flicker when you scroll (however it's acceptable). First you have to add a `VScrollBar` right on the right of your panel and a `HScrollBar` right under the bottom of your panel. This demo requires you have a `VScrollBar` named `vScrollBar1` and `HScrollBar` named `hScrollBar1`, a `Button` named `buttonOpenImage` to allow user to open some image, a `Panel` named `panel1` used as the main area to draw the image:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        //To prevent/eliminate flicker, do this
        typeof(Panel).GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", 
                                  System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | 
               System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(panel1, true, null);
        //------------------------
        UpdateScrollbarsState();
    }        
    int imgWidth, imgHeight;
    Image image;
    Point leftTop = Point.Empty;
    int lastV, lastH;
    private void OpenImage(){
        OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();            
        openFile.FileOk += (s, e) => {
            try {
                image = Image.FromFile(openFile.FileName);
                //calculate the physical size of the image based on the resolution and its logical size.
                //We have to do this because the DrawImage is based on the physical size (not logical).
                imgWidth = (int)(image.Width * 96f / image.HorizontalResolution + 0.5);
                imgHeight = (int)(image.Height * 96f / image.VerticalResolution + 0.5);
                lastV = lastH = 0;
                UpdateScrollbarsState();
                vScrollBar1.Value = 0;
                hScrollBar1.Value = 0;
                panel1.Invalidate();
            }
            catch {
                image = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Image file is invalid or corrupted!");
            }
        };
        openFile.ShowDialog();
    }
    private void UpdateScrollbarsState() {
        //We have to update all the info about Minimum and Maximum
        vScrollBar1.Minimum = 0;
        hScrollBar1.Minimum = 0;
        vScrollBar1.Maximum = Math.Max(imgHeight-panel1.Height,0);
        hScrollBar1.Maximum = Math.Max(imgWidth-panel1.Width,0);
        vScrollBar1.Visible = vScrollBar1.Maximum > 0;
        hScrollBar1.Visible = hScrollBar1.Maximum > 0;
        if (vScrollBar1.Maximum == 0) {
            leftTop.Y = 0;
            lastV = 0;
        }
        if (hScrollBar1.Maximum == 0) {
            leftTop.X = 0;
            lastH = 0;
        }
    }
    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
        if (image == null) return;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, leftTop);
    }
    //The ValueChanged event handler of your vScrollBar1
    private void vScrollBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!vScrollBar1.Visible) return;
        leftTop.Offset(0, -vScrollBar1.Value + lastV);
        lastV = vScrollBar1.Value;
        panel1.Invalidate();
    }
    //The ValueChanged event handler of your hScrollBar1
    private void hScrollBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!hScrollBar1.Visible) return;
        leftTop.Offset(lastH - hScrollBar1.Value, 0);
        lastH = hScrollBar1.Value;
        panel1.Invalidate();
    }
    //handler for SizeChanged event of the panel. However if resizing
    //the form causes the panel's size changing, you should attach this 
    //handler for form.
    private void panel1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        UpdateScrollbarsState();
    }
    //handler for the Click event of a button (click to open an image)
    private void buttonOpenImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        OpenImage();
    }
}
```

Comment: scroll bars should be added to form or panel ?

Comment: @Anand that does not really matter. However you should note that if adding the scrollbar on the panel, it will hide the image a little unless you minus some offset from the `Maximum` of the scrollbars. I updated the demo above with some fixes (it's more complete now), you can copy and try it yourself. Of course there may be some bug (Winforms is really buggy and requires many tests and fixes) but it should be little. I now focus mainly on ***WPF***. `Winforms` was my past field of interest and I just work on some Winforms project if it's a must-do.

Answer (score 5):

You can use PictureBox with SizeMode set to AutoSize and AutoScroll property of Panel. That way the panel should add scrollbars if they are needed.

```
PictureBox pictureBox = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
pictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(@"../../Data/#3_Page2.PNG");
pictureBox.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;

panel.AutoScroll = true;
panel.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox);
```

Comment: He wants to draw his image, not using picturebox.

Comment: He got into trouble by wanting to draw his image.  It is entirely unclear why he wants to do so, this answer gives a decent solution.